# How to prove that $b_n=\frac{7n-19}{3n+7}$ converges to $\frac73$?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation

How to prove that $b_n=\frac{7n-19}{3n+7}$ converges to $\frac73$?

In other words, we want to prove $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N\in  \mathbb{R}$ such that $n>N\implies |\frac{7n-19}{3n+7}-\frac73|<\epsilon$.

My scratch: $|\frac{7n-19}{3n+7}-\frac73|=\frac{106}{3(3n+7)}=\frac{106}{9n+21}\lt\epsilon$, then $n>\frac{106-21\epsilon}{9}$, so we can pick $N=\frac{106-21\epsilon}{9}$.

Formal: Let $\epsilon>0$, let $N=\frac{106-21\epsilon}{9}$, then $n>\frac{106-21\epsilon}{9}$, then $\frac{106}{3(3n+7)}\lt \epsilon$, then $|\frac{7n-19}{3n+7}-\frac73|\lt\epsilon.$

However, the answer gives that we should pick $N=\max\{1,\frac{106-21\epsilon}{9}\}$. Why is the $1$ significant?

Comment: What happens if $\frac{106-21\epsilon}{9}<0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we don't know if $\frac{106-21\epsilon}{9}$ is positive or negative. So it is appropriate to take $N>$max{$1,\frac{106-21\epsilon}{9}$} since $N$ has to a natural number. If $\frac{106-21\epsilon}{9}$ turns out to be negative or even less than 1, taking a $N\geq1$ will work.

Comment: So it should be $N\in \mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: YES! It is a sequence so you have to index it by natural numbers.

Comment: Suppose in some way we have $N=\frac{1}{9\epsilon}$, so the minimum of $N$ is 0, do we still need $N=\max\{1,\frac{1}{9\epsilon}\}$?

Comment: Why do you need a minimum? And it is okay for $N$ to be a real number but it's just standard to take it to be a natural number

Answer (score 0):

$1$ would not be significant if you wanted to prove the existence of a positive integer $N$, which is indeed what we do in proving convergence of a sequence. But what *you* need is $N\in\mathbb{R}$. However the domain of the sequence is $\mathbb{Z^+}$. So you need to make sure that everything that comes after your selected $N$ is positive.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence given above is monotone and bounded. Hence convergent. Use this fact.